# dplyr mutate, replace, and column lengths

Tags: r, replace, dplyr

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(col1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
             col2 = c(NA, NaN, Inf, 5),
             col3 = c(NA, NaN, Inf, 5))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   col1   col2  col3
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 A        NA    NA
#> 2 B       NaN   NaN
#> 3 C       Inf   Inf
#> 4 D         5     5
```

I'd like to replace `col2` column values `NA` and `NaN` with `0`. I'm aware I could do this with the `replace_na()` function, but instead am trying it in the following manner... and getting this column length error.

```
df %>% mutate(col2 = replace(col2, is.na(.), 0))
#> Error: Column `col2` must be length 4 (the number of rows) or one, not 12
```

`col2` is indeed four rows in length, not twelve. Is the error misleading or am I misinterpreting something? And what to do to correct it?

Comment: You probably need `is.na(col2)` as the `.` will refer to `df` (which has 12 elements)

Comment: You can use `replace_na` `df %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, replace_na, 0)`

Comment: @Andrew Gustar that worked, so easy! Do you want to writeup as answer so I can mark solved and credit you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `.` in your statement is referring to `df` (which has 12 elements), not to `col2`.  You need to write `is.na(col2)` explicitly...

```
df %>% mutate(col2 = replace(col2, is.na(col2), 0))
```

Alternatively you can use `replace_na`, which is designed just for this purpose...

```
df %>% mutate(col2 = replace_na(col2, 0))
```